# Create a multi layer tiff without visible modification in wand/imagemagic/python/js

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

I need to create a multi layer tif and when I open in photoshop in need to be as separated layers like in the picture:

[image: photoshop with tif]

I need to do it without photoshop so I though so that I can do with Wand in python:

```
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename="./GPD_TEST_Product.png") as img:
    img.read(filename="./GPD_TEST_Reflection.png")
    img.read(filename="./GPD_TEST_Shadow.png")
    img.read(filename="./GPD_TEST_Background.png")  
    img.save(filename="final.tif")
```

but when I open it with photoshop I got:

[image: tif without laters]

but when I open it with preview on mac I can see the layers...

[image: layers in preview]

My other idea is to create a psd with layers and try to convert it to .tif with imagemagic, but still when I open it with photoshop, is merged.

here is the file which I'm working on:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ioWG2rJ32FVstUYJK8ITuhmGSUr7I_Ps?fbclid=IwAR1HtNsChsr6befuUTPHklqKREtwxCMLk39cRhbeshio_MU0fGU-P35kxlU

Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: As far as I know, currently, Imagemagick cannot create a multi-layer tiff, only a multi-page tiff.

Comment: Do you know how to do with psdtags? maybe do you have any example to build from multiple of pngs, a layered tif?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layer and thumbnail image and metadata of layered TIFF files are stored in the ImageResources (#34377) and ImageSourceData (#37724) TIFF tags. The [psdtags](https://github.com/cgohlke/psdtags) Python library can read and write those tags but creating the tags from scratch requires knowledge of the format. Something like [this](https://github.com/cgohlke/psdtags/issues/4#issuecomment-1349677697) should work (I don't have Photoshop to verify):

```
from psdtags import *
from tifffile import imwrite
from imagecodecs import imread

background = imread('GPD_TEST_Background.png')
product = imread('GPD_TEST_Product.png')
reflection = imread('GPD_TEST_Reflection.png')
shadow = imread('GPD_TEST_Shadow.png')

image_source_data = TiffImageSourceData(
    name='Layered TIFF Test',
    psdformat=PsdFormat.LE32BIT,
    layers=PsdLayers(
        key=PsdKey.LAYER,
        has_transparency=False,
        layers=[
            PsdLayer(
                name='Background',
                rectangle=PsdRectangle(0, 0, *background.shape[:2]),
                channels=[
                    PsdChannel(
                        channelid=PsdChannelId.CHANNEL0,
                        compression=PsdCompressionType.RLE,
                        data=background[..., 0],
                    ),
                    PsdChannel(
                        channelid=PsdChannelId.CHANNEL1,
                        compression=PsdCompressionType.RLE,
                        data=background[..., 1],
                    ),
                    PsdChannel(
                        channelid=PsdChannelId.CHANNEL2,
                        compression=PsdCompressionType.RLE,
                        data=background[..., 2],
                    ),
                ],
                mask=PsdLayerMask(),
                opacity=255,
                blendmode=PsdBlendMode.NORMAL,
                blending_ranges=(),
                clipping=PsdClippingType.BASE,
                flags=PsdLayerFlag.PHOTOSHOP5
                | PsdLayerFlag.TRANSPARENCY_PROTECTED,
                info=[
                    PsdString(PsdKey.UNICODE_LAYER_NAME, 'Background'),
                ],
            ),
            PsdLayer(
                name='Reflection',
                rectangle=PsdRectangle(0, 0, *reflection.shape[:2]),
                channels=[
                    PsdChannel(
                        channelid=PsdChannelId.TRANSPARENCY_MASK,
                        compression=PsdCompressionType.RLE,
                        data=reflection[..., 3],
                    ),
                    PsdChannel(
                        channelid=PsdChannelId.CHANNEL0,
                        compression=PsdCompressionType.RLE,
                        data=reflection[..., 0],
                    ),
                    PsdChannel(
                        channelid=PsdChannelId.CHANNEL1,
                        compression=PsdCompressionType.RLE,
                        data=reflection[..., 1],
                    ),
                    PsdChannel(
                        channelid=PsdChannelId.CHANNEL2,
                        compression=PsdCompressionType.RLE,
                        data=reflection[..., 2],
                    ),
                ],
                mask=PsdLayerMask(),
                opacity=255,
                blendmode=PsdBlendMode.NORMAL,
                blending_ranges=(),
                clipping=PsdClippingType.BASE,
                flags=PsdLayerFlag.PHOTOSHOP5,
                info=[
                    PsdString(PsdKey.UNICODE_LAYER_NAME, 'Reflection'),
                ],
            ),
            PsdLayer(
                name='Shadow',
                rectangle=PsdRectangle(0, 0, *shadow.shape[:2]),
                channels=[
                    PsdChannel(
                        channelid=PsdChannelId.TRANSPARENCY_MASK,
                        compression=PsdCompressionType.RLE,
                        data=shadow[..., 3],
                    ),
                    PsdChannel(
                        channelid=PsdChannelId.CHANNEL0,
                        compression=PsdCompressionType.RLE,
                        data=shadow[..., 0],
                    ),
                    PsdChannel(
                        channelid=PsdChannelId.CHANNEL1,
                        compression=PsdCompressionType.RLE,
                        data=shadow[..., 1],
                    ),
                    PsdChannel(
                        channelid=PsdChannelId.CHANNEL2,
                        compression=PsdCompressionType.RLE,
                        data=shadow[..., 2],
                    ),
                ],
                mask=PsdLayerMask(),
                opacity=255,
                blendmode=PsdBlendMode.NORMAL,
                blending_ranges=(),
                clipping=PsdClippingType.BASE,
                flags=PsdLayerFlag.PHOTOSHOP5,
                info=[
                    PsdString(PsdKey.UNICODE_LAYER_NAME, 'Shadow'),
                ],
            ),
            PsdLayer(
                name='Product',
                rectangle=PsdRectangle(0, 0, *product.shape[:2]),
                channels=[
                    PsdChannel(
                        channelid=PsdChannelId.TRANSPARENCY_MASK,
                        compression=PsdCompressionType.RLE,
                        data=product[..., 3],
                    ),
                    PsdChannel(
                        channelid=PsdChannelId.CHANNEL0,
                        compression=PsdCompressionType.RLE,
                        data=product[..., 0],
                    ),
                    PsdChannel(
                        channelid=PsdChannelId.CHANNEL1,
                        compression=PsdCompressionType.RLE,
                        data=product[..., 1],
                    ),
                    PsdChannel(
                        channelid=PsdChannelId.CHANNEL2,
                        compression=PsdCompressionType.RLE,
                        data=product[..., 2],
                    ),
                ],
                mask=PsdLayerMask(),
                opacity=255,
                blendmode=PsdBlendMode.NORMAL,
                blending_ranges=(),
                clipping=PsdClippingType.BASE,
                flags=PsdLayerFlag.PHOTOSHOP5,
                info=[
                    PsdString(PsdKey.UNICODE_LAYER_NAME, 'Product'),
                ],
            ),
        ],
    ),
    usermask=PsdUserMask(
        colorspace=PsdColorSpaceType.RGB,
        components=(65535, 0, 0, 0),
        opacity=50,
    ),
    info=[
        PsdEmpty(PsdKey.PATTERNS),
        PsdFilterMask(
            colorspace=PsdColorSpaceType.RGB,
            components=(65535, 0, 0, 0),
            opacity=50,
        ),
    ],
)

imwrite(
    'LayeredTiffTest.tif',
    background,
    photometric='rgb',
    metadata=None,
    extratags=[image_source_data.tifftag()],
)

print(TiffImageSourceData.fromtiff('LayeredTiffTest.tif'))
```

Comment: WOW this is awesome! It's working as a charm!

Comment: I have a problem with this script, in photoshop it's working well, I've seen the layers but when I'd like to open the tiff with normal preview (on mac or windows) I see only white background. here you can see the file on the left is with script and on right when I save the same with photoshop: https://imgur.com/zyr2Rmj

Comment: The preview shows a white background because the script writes the background as the main TIFF image: `imwrite(..., background, ...)`. Replace `background` with a composited image if you need compatibility with non-Photoshop apps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, you have complete right. When I put product instead of background I got circle instead of empty. I tried to composited imaged with `from wand.image import Image` 

`with Image(filename="./GPD_TEST_Product.png") as img:
    img.read(filename="./GPD_TEST_Reflection.png")
    img.read(filename="./GPD_TEST_Shadow.png")
    img.read(filename="./GPD_TEST_Background.png")`
but I got an error `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'Image'` I'm wondering if I should use i`magecodecs` somehow, but I completely don't know this library.

Comment: I found also with PIL libary: `Image.composite(im1, im2, mask)` but what happen if I edit blendmode or opacity for different, the "thumbnail" will be not propitiate. Maybe can I convert `TiffImageSourceData` into static png image and put it as main tiff?

Answer (score -1):

If anyone need generating tiff with layers and thumbnail is not white background but composite image here is my solution:

```
from psdtags import *
from tifffile import imwrite
from imagecodecs import imread
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image


# backgroundImage = Image.open('GPD_TEST_Background.png')
productImage = Image.open('GPD_TEST_Product.png')
reflectionImage = Image.open('GPD_TEST_Reflection.png')
shadowImage = Image.open('GPD_TEST_Shadow.png')

w, h = productImage.size

# create background with defined color
backgroundImage = Image.new(mode="RGBA", size=(w,h), color=(255, 255, 255,255))

background = np.array(backgroundImage)
product = np.array(productImage)
reflection = np.array(reflectionImage)
shadow = np.array(shadowImage)

#thumbnail
thumbnail = Image.alpha_composite(backgroundImage, reflectionImage)
thumbnail = Image.alpha_composite(thumbnail, shadowImage)
thumbnail = Image.alpha_composite(thumbnail, productImage)
thumbnail = np.array(thumbnail)

image_source_data = TiffImageSourceData(
    name='Layered TIFF Test',
    psdformat=PsdFormat.LE32BIT,
    layers=PsdLayers(
        key=PsdKey.LAYER,
        has_transparency=False,
        layers=[
            PsdLayer(
                name='Background',
                rectangle=PsdRectangle(0, 0, *background.shape[:2]),
                channels=[
                    PsdChannel(
                        channelid=PsdChannelId.CHANNEL0,
                        compression=PsdCompressionType.RLE,
                        data=background[..., 0],
                    ),
                    PsdChannel(
                        channelid=PsdChannelId.CHANNEL1,
                        compression=PsdCompressionType.RLE,
                        data=background[..., 1],
                    ),
                    PsdChannel(
                        channelid=PsdChannelId.CHANNEL2,
                        compression=PsdCompressionType.RLE,
                        data=background[..., 2],
                    ),
                ],
                mask=PsdLayerMask(),
                opacity=255,
                blendmode=PsdBlendMode.NORMAL,
                blending_ranges=(),
                clipping=PsdClippingType.BASE,
                flags=PsdLayerFlag.PHOTOSHOP5
                | PsdLayerFlag.TRANSPARENCY_PROTECTED,
                info=[
                    PsdString(PsdKey.UNICODE_LAYER_NAME, 'Background'),
                ],
            ),
            PsdLayer(
                name='Reflection',
                rectangle=PsdRectangle(0, 0, *reflection.shape[:2]),
                channels=[
                    PsdChannel(
                        channelid=PsdChannelId.TRANSPARENCY_MASK,
                        compression=PsdCompressionType.RLE,
                        data=reflection[..., 3],
                    ),
                    PsdChannel(
                        channelid=PsdChannelId.CHANNEL0,
                        compression=PsdCompressionType.RLE,
                        data=reflection[..., 0],
                    ),
                    PsdChannel(
                        channelid=PsdChannelId.CHANNEL1,
                        compression=PsdCompressionType.RLE,
                        data=reflection[..., 1],
                    ),
                    PsdChannel(
                        channelid=PsdChannelId.CHANNEL2,
                        compression=PsdCompressionType.RLE,
                        data=reflection[..., 2],
                    ),
                ],
                mask=PsdLayerMask(),
                opacity=255,
                blendmode=PsdBlendMode.NORMAL,
                blending_ranges=(),
                clipping=PsdClippingType.BASE,
                flags=PsdLayerFlag.PHOTOSHOP5,
                info=[
                    PsdString(PsdKey.UNICODE_LAYER_NAME, 'Reflection'),
                ],
            ),
            PsdLayer(
                name='Shadow',
                rectangle=PsdRectangle(0, 0, *shadow.shape[:2]),
                channels=[
                    PsdChannel(
                        channelid=PsdChannelId.TRANSPARENCY_MASK,
                        compression=PsdCompressionType.RLE,
                        data=shadow[..., 3],
                    ),
                    PsdChannel(
                        channelid=PsdChannelId.CHANNEL0,
                        compression=PsdCompressionType.RLE,
                        data=shadow[..., 0],
                    ),
                    PsdChannel(
                        channelid=PsdChannelId.CHANNEL1,
                        compression=PsdCompressionType.RLE,
                        data=shadow[..., 1],
                    ),
                    PsdChannel(
                        channelid=PsdChannelId.CHANNEL2,
                        compression=PsdCompressionType.RLE,
                        data=shadow[..., 2],
                    ),
                ],
                mask=PsdLayerMask(),
                opacity=255,
                blendmode=PsdBlendMode.NORMAL,
                blending_ranges=(),
                clipping=PsdClippingType.BASE,
                flags=PsdLayerFlag.PHOTOSHOP5,
                info=[
                    PsdString(PsdKey.UNICODE_LAYER_NAME, 'Shadow'),
                ],
            ),
            PsdLayer(
                name='Product',
                rectangle=PsdRectangle(0, 0, *product.shape[:2]),
                channels=[
                    PsdChannel(
                        channelid=PsdChannelId.TRANSPARENCY_MASK,
                        compression=PsdCompressionType.RLE,
                        data=product[..., 3],
                    ),
                    PsdChannel(
                        channelid=PsdChannelId.CHANNEL0,
                        compression=PsdCompressionType.RLE,
                        data=product[..., 0],
                    ),
                    PsdChannel(
                        channelid=PsdChannelId.CHANNEL1,
                        compression=PsdCompressionType.RLE,
                        data=product[..., 1],
                    ),
                    PsdChannel(
                        channelid=PsdChannelId.CHANNEL2,
                        compression=PsdCompressionType.RLE,
                        data=product[..., 2],
                    ),
                ],
                mask=PsdLayerMask(),
                opacity=255,
                blendmode=PsdBlendMode.NORMAL,
                blending_ranges=(),
                clipping=PsdClippingType.BASE,
                flags=PsdLayerFlag.PHOTOSHOP5,
                info=[
                    PsdString(PsdKey.UNICODE_LAYER_NAME, 'Product'),
                ],
            ),
        ],
    ),
    usermask=PsdUserMask(
        colorspace=PsdColorSpaceType.RGB,
        components=(65535, 0, 0, 0),
        opacity=50,
    ),
    info=[
        PsdEmpty(PsdKey.PATTERNS),
        PsdFilterMask(
            colorspace=PsdColorSpaceType.RGB,
            components=(65535, 0, 0, 0),
            opacity=50,
        ),
    ],
)


imwrite(
    'LayeredTiffTest.tif',
    thumbnail,
    photometric='rgb',
    metadata=None,
    extratags=[image_source_data.tifftag()],
)

print(TiffImageSourceData.fromtiff('LayeredTiffTest.tif'))
```

What do you think about it?